# Grails: GSP variable substitution in g:each tag

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a loop inside a loop and want to substitute the value of first var into second. Below is the code snippet.

```
<g:each in="${tables}" status="i" var="table">
    <div class="tabletitle">
        ${table.name}
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <g:each in="${${table.name}DisplayColumns}" status="k" var="displayColumn">
                <td>${displayColumn}</td>
            </g:each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ....
            ....
        </tbody>
    </table>
</g:each>
```

${table.name} substitution in second g:each tag is not working. Any idea to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <g:each in="${evaluate(table.name+'DisplayColumns')}" status="k" var="displayColumn">
```

Comment: That didn't work. It is iterating for each letter in the string 'DevDisplayColumns' where table.name resulted into 'Dev', but expected was to substitute ${DevDisplayColumns} with actual array list.

Comment: if you can do that, wouldn't it be the same to do `<g:each in="${table.name+'DisplayColumns'}" ...` ?

Comment: No - this was my mistake from  earlier.  That creates a string, and the iteration is then over each letter in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I've never used evaluate inside a gsp, as Kelly suggests. But may I suggest a less optimal approach?

You can store `${table.name}` inside a variable with `<g:set>` ( http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/set.html )

Comment: Actually GalmWing I tried that as well as a test - again it creates a string if you do <g:set var="tempName" value="${table.name}" /> and then concatenate tempName + 'DisplayColumns' which a makes the iteration over a string. Then you end up with each <td /> having one letter of the string like '<td>D</td><td>e</td><td>v</td>' etc.

Comment: Yes, I realized my terrible mistake. And just out of curiosity, why don't you handle that logic in the Controller? you can pass directly a list that contains the DisplayColumns. And since you are already using `status`, you can do something like <g:each in="${DisplayColumns[i]}"

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that you can pass any object to a GSP? Even maps (you're trying to emulate maps, I don't know why), and use it like:

```
<g:each in="${displayColumns[table.name]}">
```

where displayColumns is a Map that contains columns for each table.

Btw, more clean way, is to use special object, that includes this data. Something like `TableDetails` that have `List<String> getColumns()` method. So you can use

```
<g:each in="${tables}" var="table">

   ${table.name}

   <g:each in="${table.columns}" var="column">
     ${column}
   </g:each>

</g:each>
```

Comment: Above solution from Kelly worked for me. The problem was that the key names in the map were partly stored in variables so evaluate() worked easily for me. Haven't tried your solution though; Thanks.